# Can the shortest path problem be solved using Monte Carlo Tree Search?

Tags: search-algorithms, shortest-path, monte-carlo

I think Monte Carlo Tree Search could be used to find the shortest path, but it seems that this method is only used considering win/lose outcomes in the simulation step.

If we consider the path length as the outcome for the simulation step, how would the back propagation work? It seems that one of the nodes along the optimal path could be penalized if a child ends up with long path in the simulation step.

Comment: I made a [Monte Carlo tree search (MCTS) algorithm for the travelling salesman problem](https://github.com/Butanium/monte-carlo-tree-search-and-TSP) inspired by [this paper](http://sasimi.jp/new/sasimi2016/files/archive/pdf/p352_R4-14.pdf) which explains how to do such thing. However the algorithm described in the paper is very slow and needs a lot of improvement. I'll try to improve it by shortening the playoff/playout phase and adding some local optimization in the playout